# Spark-redshift pushed down filters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-redshift

I am using spark-redshift to read data from Redshift cluster. Code example:

```
 spark.read
  .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")
  .option("url", s"$redshiftUrl/$redshiftDatabase")
  .option("user", redshiftUsername)
  .option("password", redshiftPassword)
  .option("tempdir", s"s3a://$redshiftTempBucket")
  .option("driver", redshiftDriver)
  .option("tempformat", "CSV GZIP")
  .option("aws_iam_role", redshiftAwsIamRole)
  .option("dbtable", s"${table.schema}.${table.name}")
  .load()
  .filter(col("SOME_COLUMN_TO_FILTER_BY") === lit(23))
```

Extended physical plan looks like:

```
    == Physical Plan ==
InMemoryTableScan [columns..., ... 45 more fields]
   +- InMemoryRelation [columns..., ... 45 more fields], StorageLevel(disk, memory, deserialized, 1 replicas)
         +- *(1) Filter (cast(SOME_COLUMN_TO_FILTER_BY#7022 as bigint) = 23)
            +- *(1) Scan RedshiftRelation(${table.schema}.${table.name}) [columns...,... 45 more fields] PushedFilters: [*IsNotNull(SOME_COLUMN_TO_FILTER_BY)], ReadSchema: struct<...>
```

So, as you can see in PushedFilters we have only check for IsNotNull and no equality to 23: `PushedFilters: [*IsNotNull(SOME_COLUMN_TO_FILTER_BY)]`

As a result, query that Redshift uses to unload data to S3:

```
SELECT columns... FROM "schema"."table" WHERE "SOME_COLUMN_TO_FILTER_BY" IS NOT NULL
```

My question: Why equality to 23 wasn't pushed down to query that Redshift uses to unload the data to S3?

Comment: any update on this... I am seeing similar problem

Comment: I think I just passed filter as part of redshift query